# Wine - Make WinMerge treat different case files and folders names as distinct files and folders

Tags: wine, winmerge

Is it possible to make WinMerge treat different case (case-sensitive) files and folders names as distinct files and folders?

**NOTE I:** I am running "WinMerge" over "Wine" (Linux).
**NOTE II:** As we know the "default" Linux file system is case sensitive different from the "default" Windows file system. So we are looking for a workaround for this problem.
**IMPORTANT:** We have particular reasons for using "WinMerge" in Wine, so we do not look for other alternatives for "diff tools".

**WinMerge behavior (Wine):**
[image]

**Meld behavior (Linux native):**
[image]

Comment: If turning on the option to treat case-sensitive items differently does not cut it, you might simply have to compare these "duplicates" directly.

Comment: @Anaksunaman That was also the solution I found too! Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. =)

Comment: @Anaksunaman Yes! This is a side effect (Wine) of adapting Windows file system to the Linux file system. I believe there is nothing to do but a modification in the WinMerge code.